# Spring Boot Cloud Eureka on Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic12c, netflix-eureka

Iv'e been struggling with recent weblogic updates to get eureka up and running. I've followed every hint and tip to no avail. Simple issue is weblogic is using a later version of jersey that eureka server uses internally.

For the life of me I cannot figure out what combination of preferred libs and adhod additional dependencies I need to setup to get this going.

Happy yo supply all the nitty gritty but essentially its spring boot starter 1.5.13.RELEASE with cloud dependencies at Edgware.SR4 on Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 deployed as a war file

Comment: You probably need the whole tree of transitive dependencies from the version of jersey that you want in the preferred libs.  FWIW, in my experience you're better off conforming to weblogic then trying to get weblogic to anything other then what it wants too.\

Comment: You can't conform in this case because Netflix Eureka uses the older Jersey 1.x libs

Comment: Are you handcuffed to weblogic?